# Swift Build Dynamic Apps

Tags: ios, swift

I want to develop an app, which can be modified programmatically. In my config.swift file, I save the main settings for my app. For example: If I want to create 5 textfields, I set a variable for that (in config.swift) and this will create me five textfields. This works perfectly! But as I do everything programmatically (e.g. adding textfields), I don't have the advantages of the visual storyboard. Is there a way to create UIElements dynamically, without dispensing the advantages of a storyboard?

Comment: ... doesn't the dynamics defeat the purpose of the storyboard? The idea of the storyboard is to visually plan out your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you can create in the `Storyboard` can be created in code. When you create your Storyboard it is set with that structure, but when you create it programmatically it´s more dynamic and you can create elements "on the fly".

The main advantage with the Storyboard is that you get a visual overview of your layout. Up to you to choose what suits your needs best.

Comment: My main problem is that I'm fed up with my workflow (while using "dynamic style"). I always have to run the app to see my changements. Is there any possibility do create an viewable xml-file on the fly, in order to see these changements?

Comment: @AlexanderJeitler-Stehr, I´m not quite sure that that would work and how unfortunately.